# magento auto set country in checkout

Tags: checkout, language

About magento auto set country in checkout

**Question:** How can we set the dropdown in Magento checkout with countries to the actual country the customer is coming from (on multicountry frontend).

(ofcourse we can set a default per store view - but alas, we have an english version that works for *all* countries. It would be nice if the country is then already set to the right country)

ideas: read requested country/language in reques? Geoip database?

What is maybe the simplest way? and the maybe the best way?

thx

Answer (score 1):

There are already GeoIp databases. A free one is available here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/geoip.html

Some code samples are already available on GitHub.

Using that you could try to develop your own extension but there are already a few on the market:

http://www.gomage.com/extensions/gomage-lightcheckout.html?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=lightcheckout&utm_campaign=lightcheckout

http://magento-one-step-checkout-extension.cmsmart.net/magento-extensions/magento-one-step-checkout-extension